# How to make sure server keeps connection with client

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, security, nowjs-sockets

I am developing a videochat application using a PHP framework, Red5 server and now.js framework for node.js. Whenever two users enter private chat, one of them is paying and the other one is receiving that amount. Now, I need to make sure that database update of the cash balance is performed every minute - if I were to use javascript to do ajax posts, how can I make sure the payee didn't somehow prevent those posts? Or should I use different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay - How to make sure that ajax post is performed every minute?

Comment: Why dont you tell the Node.js server how much cash the user has at the beginning of the session then remove an amount on the server side? That way there's no tampering.

Comment: Where is the video stream routed? If not via your server, have you the ability to stop the feed?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` to call a function which uses ajax

Comment: I know how to make those calls, I want to know how to make sure the user didn't prevent them on the client side.

Comment: Why don't you wait until the end of the session and calculate the total time and charge accordingly. I'm not following your logic.